# How can I remove size class from Xcode 6.2?

Tags: ios, xcode-6.2

I'm working in a new App using Xcode 6.2 but now I want to remove the size class from my storyboard but I don't find the option to remove it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default setting for any project in Xcode 6.x has Auto Layout and Size Classes enabled. You can disable them manually using below steps :

1. Select *View Controller* present in *Main.Storyboard*
2. Click on *Utilities* if it is hidden
3. Click on *Show file inspector*
4. In *Interface Builder Document* section simply uncheck *Use Size Classes*.

[image: Screenshot for step 2 to 4]

5. This will prompt a message *Disable Size Classes?*
6. Click on *Disable Size Classes*

[image: Screenshot for Step 5 to 6]

Answer (score 3):

Go to the file inspector of the storyboard and uncheck "Use Size Classes".[image]

Comment: I don't have the 2 options: in the standard Xcode (no beta) I have these two options but in the Xcode 6.2beta I don't have the options...

Comment: Then this is a bug. I'm running Xcode 6.3 beta and there these options exist.